# SPFx - Add/Remove form fields

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I need to create a custom page where the fields can be configurable. We need to create it as SPFx web part.
In the property pane, we want to provision a JSON which users with proper permission can edit. And whatever field names are mentioned in JSON, we want to show those fields on the form where end users can enter values.

The controls are predefined like textbox, drop-down & date. Can anyone lead me to proper link/article how to achieve this?

Thanks,
Sanjay

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example: https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-list-form

I believe it will do most of what you're looking for.

I hope this helps?